# Issues getting data from array's dictionary JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, dictionary

I'm having issues to get the stored data in my array. I can't see where is the problem on my function and why is returning undefined elements.

This is the function where I store data in the array:

```
function getTaskKidData(str) {
   var tasks = $('#tasks_data > div');;
   var formated_tasks = [];
   var formated_kids = [];
   formated_homeworks = [];
   tasks.each(function(index) {
       var task_kids = $(this).find('ul').eq(0).find('li');
       var task_homeworks = $(this).find('ul').eq(1).find('li');
       if (task_kids.length > 0 && task_homeworks.length > 0) {
           task_kids.each(function(index) {
               var kid_name = $(this).text().trim();
               if (str == "kid"){
                   var kid = $('#kid_list > li > a[class*="active"]').text().replace(window.location.pathname.split('/')[2],'').trim();
                   if (kid == kid_name){
                       formated_kids.push({'name': kid_name});
                   }
               }else{
                   formated_kids.push({'name': kid_name});
               }
           });
           task_homeworks.each(function(index) {
               var homework_name = $(this).find('p').eq(0).text().trim();
               var homework_date = $(this).find('p').eq(1).text().trim();
               formated_homeworks.push({
                   'name': homework_name,
                   'date': homework_date,
               });
           });
           formated_tasks.push({
               'kids': task_kids,
               'homeworks': task_homeworks,
           })
       }
   });
   return formated_tasks;
}
```

**I don't understand why the objects in the output of the array are "li" tags if I'm storing data as text.** The output of the array is the next one:
[image]
This is the code where I'm trying to get the data:

```
var tasks = getTaskKidData("kid");
console.log(tasks)
       for (let i = 0; i < tasks.length; i++) {
           console.log("schedule");
           for (let j = 0; j < tasks[i]['kids'].length; j++) {
               console.log(tasks[i]['kids'][j]['name']);
           }
           for (let j = 0; j < tasks[i]['homeworks'].length; j++) {
               console.log(tasks[i]['homeworks'][j]['name']);
               console.log(tasks[i]['homeworks'][j]['date']);
           }
       }
```

And this is the output when I run the code:

[image]

Any idea of the problem?

Thanks for reading!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code you have

```
var task_kids = $(this).find('ul').eq(0).find('li');
```

and later you log task_kids. The log output shows li elements because that was what you selected.